# React app hosted on Heroku failing to open pages with a URL that has more than 1 segment

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have a React web app (https://muzenda-frontend.herokuapp.com/) which I have hosted on Heroku. The other pages display well but when the url has more than 1 segment it only displays a white screen. For example a https://muzenda-frontend.herokuapp.com// will display a blank white screen. An actual live example is https://muzenda-frontend.herokuapp.com/explore/data-scientist.

My package.json contains the following

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.30",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap-4-pagination": "^1.0.4",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^6.2.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-field-validator": "^0.2.2",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
    "react-inputs-validation": "^4.6.3",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "serve": "^12.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "homepage": "."
}
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi 

Thanks for the hint, but which other code do you think I should send which helps others understand the problem. Should it be like all code for the project?